# Dependency Injection on Mapper and Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to inject a class in my mapper and reduce function. Is there any method that I can use to pass an instance of an object and inside mapper/reduce I can get the same instance?

Probably using the configuration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using guice it is easy. Otherwise I think you may be out of luck since hadoop uses reflection to construct your mapper and reducer.

The Mapper and Reducer classes have an empty method for setup(); This is where I inject my dependencies.

```
/**
 * Called once at the beginning of the task.
 */
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    IOCJobInjector.getInjector().injectMembers(this);
}
```